# my smooth model has strange bumps

Tags: modeling, materials

I really have no idea why there are these bumps in the robot's chest

It doesnt look like there should be any in wireframe[image]

But they show up in renders and solid mode[image][image]

Also the customer said that the robot looks a bit too plastic and I should make him more fun. I gave him a shadeless freestyle version and said that he didnt like it, any ideas on how I can improve this model?
http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=50764

UPDATE: Don't be an idio and just use edge split. Honestly, shouldve tried it sooner

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Applied boolean modifier leaving shading artifacts with flat shading](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13554/applied-boolean-modifier-leaving-shading-artifacts-with-flat-shading)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont be an idiot like me and try using edge split in the modifiers tab. I remember having this problem before and it's caused by booleans and I fixed it many times before with edge split, so I have no idea how I was dumb enough to not think of that. Don't drink and model, kids, that never goes well