# Shading after Boolean

Tags: modifiers, shaders

How do i fix this kind of shading after using boolean mod?

[image]

EDIT:

I can make the shading better by applying the modifiers and fixing the topology this way.
[image: New Shading]
[image: New Topology]
[image: Shading without Boolean]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Applied boolean modifier leaving shading artifacts with flat shading](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13554/applied-boolean-modifier-leaving-shading-artifacts-with-flat-shading)

Comment: your boolean must have created a bad topology, maybe it would be simpler to create your holes manually

Comment: @moonboots How would i cut that kind of hole manually? And isn't there  a  way to fix the topology and shading?

Comment: All of these questions have been asked before https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5856/cutting-a-circular-hole-in-a-hollow-cylinder-without-distorting-the-cylinder also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3260/how-to-cut-a-rounded-hole-in-a-sphere/3262#3262

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there are 2 main ways to do it in a clean way: with *Boolean* or with *LoopTools* > *Circle*.

- With a *Boolean* modifier you must make sure that your boolean object is well placed and has the right amount of vertices. You will probably make some vertices merge. Don't forget to bevel the ring so that it stays clean and sharp.
- With the *LoopTools* > *Circle* tool, you must first delete some faces, use the *LoopTools* > *Circle*, then extrude inwards and close it manually.

[image]