# Shading issue with parametric modelling and booleans

Tags: modeling, modifiers, shaders

I'm new to Blender and I started to learn by modeling an old camera lens with the help of this excellent tutorial on parametric non-destructive modeling:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v9CXeprYW1M&t=1626s

I've now encountered a problem that I can't seem to find a solution. I have modeled the lens body with only about 100 vertices and a screw modifier.

[image]

I then used BoolTool to create screw holes into the lens body. However, this somehow messes the topology and creates these ugly shading issues.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea how to fix the shading without applying the screw modifier? I would like to maintain the fast editability of the lens body.

I have tried increasing the steps of the screw modifier and moving the place of the screw hole a little bit, but none of them removed the issue, just changed the appearance a little.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's spin tool.

Comment: Also related: [Shading after Boolean](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/123815/30849).

Comment: Try the edge split modifier, bevel modifier or auto smooth.

Comment: @Leander Thank you! I had auto smooth already on, but I had to play with the angle setting to get the shading better. I also had to adjust the bevel settings on some other edges of the lens body after adjusting the auto smooth angle.