# Boolean problem...Help

Tags: modifiers

I want a made circle hole in my mesh and this is happend
[image]

[image]

Comment: try to add some geometry near by.

Comment: If you go into edit mode after the boolean operation, you will see that your mesh has bad geometry that needs to be fixed. Your mesh should consist of tris and quads. Instead of boolean operations you want to use [proper geometry](https://topologyguides.com/)

Comment: As a lazy solution you can try apply Boolean, enter edit mode and create face loop of quads around hole which was cut. That should prevent from too bad shading problems

Comment: Watch this video: [8 ways of cutting holes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bc52fcrHvAA). Read also these related links: [Cutting a hole in a cylinder](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5856) and [Cutting a rounded hole in a sphere](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3260/how-to-cut-a-rounded-hole-in-a-sphere)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Applied boolean modifier leaving shading artifacts with flat shading](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13554/applied-boolean-modifier-leaving-shading-artifacts-with-flat-shading)