# Shading issues on inside surfaces when using Boolean

Tags: modifiers

I am playing around with boolean operations, and having a shading issue on the inside of my mesh when using the difference operation to cut a section out.

[image]

I was able to fix most of my issues by using Auto Smooth as spelled out [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13554/applied-boolean-modifier-leaving-shading-artifacts-with-flat-shading), but this doesn't appear to affect the inside surfaces. Any suggestions for cleaning up the shading on the inside curved surface?

Answer (score 0):

You could try shift  N to fix normals or removing doubles and if that does not work try adding an edge split modifier

Comment: Thanks. Normals were fine. Ill double check doubles.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change the smooth and autosmooth settings of the boolean object (the one that cuts away). Since the settings of that object will determine the properties of the inner surfaces (at least until you apply the modifier).

Happy Blending! :)

Comment: Thanks. I was messing around with those, but maybe I missed something.